# Should I flag questions that appear to contain suspicious code?

Tags: support, flags, code

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750342), the current version emphasizes not to run the code in the question, which I don't know whether it really contains potential hazards. Should I flag such kind of post to request immediate deletion?

Comment: Even if it *was* malicious code, why would that be sufficient criteria for its deletion? If I posted an answer that contained the line `format c:\*.*`, would you say that needed to be deleted? The lesson here is not to type and execute everything you see online. Which I cannot imagine is a lesson that anyone really needed to learn. (That said, there are *other* reasons that question needed to be deleted; and it now is.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No.

The question does not *explicitly state* that it's malicious code; it's asking whether it is and what it does. It would be extremely difficult to find it with a Google search for "how do I hack my boss's pw", even if it *is* malicious.

Let's assume for a minute that it is obviously malicious:

> heY gUYs cheCk Out tHis COOL virUs tHat I madE!!!!1!

Or something else that would be actually on-topic. Even in this case, this should not be flagged for "immediate deletion", merely *redaction*.

Aside from that, I observe that it has been closed as "too broad". I kind of agree with that. The post *technically* should have been flagged, then, but that's not the point of your question.

Comment: Even if there *was* malicious code, it wouldn't even merit *redaction*.  (If it was actually an on topic question, which this was not.)

Comment: I disagree. A question of the form `heY gUYs cheCk Out tHis COOL virUs tHat I madE!!!!1!` should definitely be immediately deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray Deleted because it contains malicious code, or deleted because, `heY gUYs cheCk Out tHis COOL <boring non-malicious program description goes here> tHat I madE!!!!1!` would be just as delete worthy?

Comment: The latter. The maliciousness or non-maliciousness of code presented as plain text is irrelevant, as far as I can see. The only time it would matter is if someone tried to embed malicious code in the Stack Snippets feature, and if that were actually possible, it would be a high-priority bug that needed to be brought to the team's attention, in addition to community-led deletion.